# HTTPoison doesn't accept this custom header

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `curl request` of the below that works but when I translate it into the below I get the following error what is wrong with this header - I feel I've done it every possible way.

```
url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download"
header = [ {"Authorization", "Bearer #{token}"}, {"Dropbox-API-Arg", "{\"path\": \"/dropboxtest/image.jpg\"}"} ]
HTTPoison.post(url=url, header=header)

** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.iolist_to_binary([{"Authorization", "Bearer <removed>"}, {"Dropbox-API-Arg", "{\"path\": \"/dropboxtest/image.jpg\"}"}])
    (hackney) /Users/casey/Dropbox/BOS Sales LLC/backyardmicro/projects/k-9dryers/software/connectk9/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:348: :hackney_request.handle_body/4
    (hackney) /Users/casey/Dropbox/BOS Sales LLC/backyardmicro/projects/k-9dryers/software/connectk9/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:83: :hackney_request.perform/2
    (hackney) /Users/casey/Dropbox/BOS Sales LLC/backyardmicro/projects/k-9dryers/software/connectk9/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:376: :hackney.send_request/2
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:796: HTTPoison.Base.request/6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want to call is [documented here](https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html#post/4).

It gets the form:

```
HTTPoison.post(url, body, headers \\ [], options \\ [])
```

So the first argument shall be the URL, then the body, and then only the headers.

By writing `HTTPoison.post(url=url, header=header)`, note that the `url=url` and  `header=header` does not really have a meaning for what you're trying to achieve, simply write, when you have an empty body:

```
HTTPoison.post(url, "", header)
```

(As a matter of recommendation, I'd rename `header` to `headers` too if I were you)